# Job hopping to pursue dream

Tags: visa, job-hopping

I have 2 years of total experience and I have been working on the most amazing company for 3 months only. However my goal is to gain experience and be sent to work in Europe which is my life goal and super uncertain.

I may soon receive  a job offer with visa from another amazing company in Europe, Where I want to work after my current job.

I have already changed jobs twice with after a few months: one was temporary and I hated it and the other was part time and not paying my bills.

Should I accept the offer if I get it or let the opportunity pass and try expatriation/new position in Europe in a few years?

I don't want to carry the job hopping stigma with me but I feel like I should embrace opportunity

Comment: If you’re planning to stay with this new company for a while then by the time you leave it won’t be an issue anymore.

Comment: Especially at the start of one's career some hops between employers/companies isn't that uncommon. Try to gain more experience and once a better opportunity comes along (like the amazing company in Europe that you mentioned) just give it a shot..

Comment: You're in a very precarious position if you've been changing jobs multiple times in a single year and are expecting employment overseas. Companies are a lot more likely to take a risk on someone who moves around a lot when they _don't_ have to sponsor your visa. I'd say either take that offer, should you get it, or plan to become a demonstrably more dependable employee to improve your odds of future offers.

Comment: are you saying the new job with the new company is in fact in Europe straightaway?  ie, if you say Yes, they will get you a visa and fly you there and you will start work?

Comment: The people who try to make job hopping a red flag are the people who are trying to keep you satisfied with your crappy pay and terrible working conditions.  Companies are not loyal to you, and you should not be loyal to them.  Do only what is best for you.

Answer (score 6):

Take the job then stay there for a number of years.

Since you want to move to Europe, it'd be a shame to pass up on an opportunity from an amazing company.  You're correct that your CV will then show a recent history of job hopping.  This will only become an issue if you want to move jobs again quickly.  If you stick with your new job for a few years, that'll reassure prospective employers.  Hopefully a move to a great company in your preferred location will mean you have no reason to look elsewhere for some time.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question could be given more precisely depending on the industry and culture. In some industries like the public sector, frequent job changes are not appreciated, whilst in sales, IT and others only a certain amount of field experience can be achieved by job changes.

It is common to see frequent job changes of career starters, to find out what field of work is appealing and also to raise the salary expectations.

On the bottom line. It is your life. Do something meaningful with it. Go to Europe.